# how to set the soft keyboard push the data up in fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, string

I have one activity and that activity having fragment, in that fragment when i focus the edittext the soft keyboard hides the edittext data how to fix the issue?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code:-

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

more info see below link :-

[virtual keyboard hiding edit text, setting from fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987044/virtual-keyboard-hiding-edit-text-setting-from-fragment)